# Item Click event on list view

Tags: android

I am doing an alert dialog with a custom list view inside but onItemClickListener not works and I don´t know why. Here is my code:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);


                    MyAdapter clad = new MyAdapter(MyFragment.this, mi);

                    lv.setAdapter(clad);

                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()  {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {

                             String titulo = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label))
                            .getText().toString();


                             if (position==0){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                           "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    dialog.setContentView(view);

                    dialog.show();

                }
            });
```

Comment: I have seen this post but the solution not works for me, somebody can help me? :)

Comment: Just simply Print toast on button click.